# SQL Server trigger comparacion de nombre insertado

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Hola soy nuevo en SQL server, les pido su ayuda tengo un problema con un trigger que debe comparar el nombre y los dos apellidos de una persona al ser insertada en una tabla llamada Cliente. Esta seria la tabla que tengo, el trigger que deberia detectar los registros duplicados en las columnas **Nombre, Ape_Paterno, Ape_Materno**, teniendo en cuenta que cree un procedimiento que me permite insertarle los datos a la tabla cliente.

```
CREATE TABLE Cliente(
Id_Cliente INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY not null,
Nombre VARCHAR(80) not null,
Ape_Paterno VARCHAR(80) not null,
Ape_Materno VARCHAR(80) not null,
Contrasenia VARBINARY(100) not null,
)

--Procedimiento para insertar clientes

create PROCEDURE altaCliente
@Nombre VARCHAR(80),
@Ape_Paterno VARCHAR(80),
@Ape_Materno VARCHAR(80),
@Contrasenia VARBINARY(100),
@Salida VARCHAR(40) OUTPUT
AS 
INSERT INTO Cliente (Nombre, Ape_Paterno, Ape_Materno, Contrasenia)
VALUES (@Nombre, @Ape_Paterno, @Ape_Materno, @Contrasenia)
SET @Salida = 'Nuevo cliente registrado'
PRINT @Salida
GO

--Trigger para comparar el nombre y los dos apellidos de la persona insertada y verificar que 
no existan personas duplicadas en la base de datos.

CREATE TRIGGER tr_clieteDuplicado ON Cliente 
FOR INSERT
AS 
DECLARE @Nombre VARCHAR(80), @Ape_Paterno VARCHAR(80), @Ape_Materno VARCHAR(80)
SELECT @Nombre = Nombre, @Ape_Paterno = Ape_Paterno, @Ape_Materno = Ape_Materno FROM inserted
IF ((SELECT COUNT(Nombre) FROM Cliente WHERE Nombre = @Nombre) > 0 AND 
    (SELECT COUNT(Ape_Paterno) FROM Cliente WHERE Ape_Paterno = @Ape_Paterno) > 0 AND
    (SELECT COUNT(Ape_Materno) FROM Cliente WHERE Ape_Materno = @Ape_Materno) > 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Nombre(s) y apellidos duplicados'
        PRINT 'Transaccion cancelada'
        ROLLBACK
    END
```

La condicional del trigger compara los nombres de la tabla cliente con el nombre insertado de ser que haya
nombres repetidos que me cuente y con ese numero hago la comparacion en la condicional.

Aqui lo que me muestra mi sql es que inserto cualquier nombre que no exista en mi tabla cliente y el trigger
no me deja agregarlo porque detecta segun esto el nombre insertado existente en la tabla cliente..
sea asi dandole nombres diferentes y iguales de nuestra tabla cliente.
Si alguien me pudiera ayudar con esto por favor!!! no se si mi condicional en el trigger este mal planteada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al momento que ejecutas el procedure *altaCliente* el registro al cual estas añadiendo se guarda en tu tabla *Cliente*, por lo que el trigger estaría validando junto con el reciente registro. Entonces, no tendrías que comparar con 0 sino con 1.

Solo modifica tu bloque IF reemplazando los 0 con 1

```
IF  ((SELECT COUNT(Nombre) FROM Cliente WHERE Nombre = @Nombre) > 1 AND
    (SELECT COUNT(Ape_Paterno) FROM Cliente WHERE Ape_Paterno = @Ape_Paterno) > 1 AND
    (SELECT COUNT(Ape_Materno) FROM Cliente WHERE Ape_Materno = @Ape_Materno) > 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Nombre(s) y apellidos duplicados'
        PRINT 'Transaccion cancelada'
        ROLLBACK
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Para empezar, creo que puedes enfocar el problema de un modo diferente.

Primero planteo el escenario y luego avanzamos.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Cliente;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Cliente(
Id_Cliente INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY not null,
Nombre VARCHAR(80) not null,
Ape_Paterno VARCHAR(80) not null,
Ape_Materno VARCHAR(80) not null,
Contrasenia VARBINARY(100) not null,
)
GO

Insert into dbo.cliente 
(Nombre, Ape_Paterno, Ape_Materno, Contrasenia)
values
('Ana','Alvarez','Fernandez',Cast('a' as varbinary(100)));

GO
```

[image: r1]

Que es un nombre + apellido + apellido único. Yo diría que una restricción y no un código que haya que calcular. Para eso tenemos diferentes alternativas.

- Alternativa Unique.

  Alter table dbo.cliente
  Add constraint uq_clienteNombreCompleto
  Unique (Nombre, Ape_Paterno, Ape_Materno);
  GO

Ahora tengo una restricción que dice que esas columnas tienen que ser únicas.

Aplico el mismo código para insertar.

```
Insert into dbo.cliente 
(Nombre, Ape_Paterno, Ape_Materno, Contrasenia)
values
('Ana','Alvarez','Fernandez',Cast('a' as varbinary(100)));
```

Y obtengo este resultado:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Infracción de la restricción
> UNIQUE KEY 'uq_clienteNombreCompleto'. No se puede insertar una clave
> duplicada en el objeto 'dbo.Cliente'. El valor de la clave duplicada
> es (Ana, Alvarez, Fernandez). Se terminó la instrucción.

- Alternativa Check

Lo primero aplico todo el código anterior, realizando el drop a la tabla, creándola de nuevo e insertando una fila.

Utilizar `check` es un pelín diferente, porque si ya tienes registros duplicados, puedes aplicar una restricción, solo para las nuevas filas, y que si se modifican muchas columnas de la tabla o una sentencia de modificación grande, no se vea truncada por un apellido repetido.

Ahora creo una función escalar que me indicará si el registro no es único para `Nombre`, `Ape_Paterno` y `Ape_Materno`

```
Create function
    dbo.clienteDuplicado
(
@Nombre VARCHAR(80),
@Ape_Paterno VARCHAR(80),
@Ape_Materno VARCHAR(80)
)
Returns tinyInt
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
As
Begin
    Declare @returnValue tinyint;
    Select @returnValue = Count(1)
        From dbo.Cliente
    Where Nombre= @Nombre 
        And Ape_Paterno = @Ape_Paterno
        And Ape_Materno = @Ape_Materno
    Return @returnValue;
End
```

Con la función creada inserto un usuario nuevo.

```
Insert into dbo.cliente 
(Nombre, Ape_Paterno, Ape_Materno, Contrasenia)
values
('Jose','Alvarez','Fernandez',Cast('C' as varbinary(100)));
GO
```

Vuelvo a repetir la inserción y me da un "zasca"

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 26 Instrucción INSERT en conflicto
> con la restricción CHECK 'Uq_duplicates_WithFnclienteDuplicado'. El
> conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos 'demo', tabla
> 'dbo.Cliente'.

Se terminó la instrucción.

Tienes más info en el enlace.

[Evitar duplicados en insert o updates](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2021/05/22/evitar-duplicados-en-updates-o-insert/)

- Alternativa Trigger

El trigger está mal planteado porque lo primero, esta pensado en insertar fila por fila, y una sentencia de inserción, puede contener varias filas, por tanto fallaría.

El segundo error de concepto, es leer muchas veces la misma tabla. Los tres counts se pueden hacer en la misma select.

Además creo que es preferible utilizar un trigger instead of insert, para que se ahorre la escritura de una inserción, que luego das para atrás si no encaja.

Una solución podría ser.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER tr_clieteDuplicado 
ON dbo.Cliente 
 Instead of INSERT
AS 
Begin
    if (exists(
    Select *
            fROM INSERTED i
            inner join dbo.cliente c
                on
                    c.Nombre      = i.Nombre
                and c.Ape_Paterno = i.Ape_Paterno
                and c.Ape_Materno = i.Ape_Materno
        ))
    BEGIN
    
            PRINT 'Nombre(s) y apellidos duplicados';
            PRINT 'Transaccion cancelada';
            ROLLBACK;
    END;
    else 
    Insert into dbo.cliente(Nombre, Ape_Paterno, Ape_Materno, Contrasenia)
    SELECT I.Nombre, I.Ape_Paterno, I.Ape_Materno, I.Contrasenia
    FROM INSERTED I;

END;
GO
```

La diferencia radica, en que ahora se evalúa el conjunto entrante con el existente y si hay coincidencia, entonces no se inserta, y se hace un rollback, en caso contrario se inserta.

Si inserto al cliente dos

```
Insert into dbo.cliente 
(Nombre, Ape_Paterno, Ape_Materno, Contrasenia)
values
('Jose','Alvarez','Fernandez',Cast('D' as varbinary(100)));
```

[image: Result3]

Pero si lo intento volver a insertar.

> Nombre(s) y apellidos duplicados Transaccion cancelada Msg 3609, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 28 La transacción terminó en el desencadenador. Se
> anuló el lote.

[Trigger after insert](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/12/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-insert/)

[Instead of](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/05/03/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-instead-of/)